# Sync data from multiple local mysql instances to one cloud database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am looking for a solution to sync data from multiply small instances to one big cloud instance.

I have many devices gathering data logs, every device has there own database, so I need a solution to sync data from them to one instance. The delay is not important but I want to sync the data with a max delay of 5-10 min.

Is there any ready solution for it?

Comment: Are the "rows" independent of each other?  That is, do they have _different_ values in the Primary and Unique columns?  This would avoid the question of whether one source needs to override another source.

Comment: Show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: "has there own database" -- Do you mean server?  Or MySQL "Database"?  Or MySQL "table"?

Comment: Server and MySql Database, the schema is the same for all

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the data is independent, `INSERT` all the data into a single table.  That table would, of course, have a `device_id` column to distinguish where the numbers are coming from.

What is the total number of rows per second you need to handle?  If less than 1000/second, there should be no problem inserting the rows into the same table *as the arrive*.

Are you using HTTP?  Or something else to do the `INSERTs`?  PHP?  Java?

With this, you will rarely see more than a 1 *second* delay between the reading being taken and the table having the value.

I recommend

```
PRIMARY KEY(device_id, datetime)
```

And the use of Summary tables rather than slogging through that big Fact table to do graphs and reports.

Provide more details if you would like further advice.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your comment. Every device, has a Node.js server. The number of rows per second is much lower than 1000.

I decided to use local databases because there is a chance to lose internet connection, so I thought to save data locally and then sync it with the cloud database.

Comment: @Vitoo - Consider storing to the main database; but if there is a failure, write to something local.  That way, you know what to push (or pull) to the main db after an outage.  What if the network outage is more than 10 minutes?